# What's the difference between "active" and "busy"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, adjectives, word-usage

What's the difference in meaning between saying "I'm an active person." and "I'm a busy person."?

Comment: What does the dictionary tell you about _active_ and _busy_?

Comment: @coleopterist Both entries say that these words mean "engaged in action". However, I see active as productive and busy as occupied (both in regard to an activity). Being a foreigner, I'd like to confirm whether there's a subtle difference or not.

Comment: Given the type of question you’ve asked, I think you might be interested in [our sister site for English Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com). ELL tends to be a better fit for these sorts of English-learner questions than ELU does.

Comment: @tchrist is it discouraged to ans this type questions (the ones which should be asked at a different place) here?

Comment: Should I delete the question and post it there?

Answer (score 1):

*[Active](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/active?q=active)* and *[Busy](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/busy?q=busy)* are both primarily used as adjectives. The OxfordOnline dictionary defines:
**Active:** engaging or ready to engage in physically energetic pursuits.
**Busy:** having a great deal to do.

So, you would say you are an active person if you do a whole bunch of things and seldom get time to just sit back and relax or do nothing.You'd say you are a busy person if you have a whole bunch of *activities* that occupy your time and self. 
So, if you are reading a book, or just sitting on your couch pondering over things, you can say you are busy. But you would restrain yourself from saying you are active while you are just sitting on the couch thinking stuff. This example suggests towards the meaning above: being active usually corresponds to being engaged in physical activities.